# 1TB ssd in late 2013 rMBP 2.4 i5

Tags: hard-drive, upgrade, macbook-pro

I bought a 13" MacBook Pro with Retina display (Late 2013, 2.4GHz i5), and it only has 128GB storage. I found a 1 TB PCIe that will fit into the rig, but I'm a little confused from what I was reading on Apple. From what I gathered, it says that the 2.6GHz i5 is configurable up to 1TB, but says nothing about the 2.4GHz. Is this just how Apple sells it - they just don't give the option for 1TB on the 2.4 - or will this much storage not actually work on this computer?

Answer (score 1):

According to the folks at iFixit, there aren't any compatible drives out yet.

Source: https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/181479/SSD+possible+%28%29+upgrade+on+ebay#answer181496